# Dissipation factor for bounded electron: meaning of non radiative component

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, classical-electrodynamics

The motion of a bounded electron can be modeled by an equation of the type
$$\ddot{x(t)}+\Gamma\dot{x(t)}+\omega_0x(t)=F(t)$$

Where $\omega_0$ is the caracteristic frequency of the elastic force and $\Gamma$ is a **dissipation** factor which is **made of two parts**

$$\Gamma=\gamma+\gamma'$$

Where $\gamma$ is the component of dissipation due to radiatice process.

My question is : what does $\gamma'$ represent instead? I know it should be related to the geometry and to interaction of electron with atoms but is this correct? Are there other effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I suppose there are a number of nonradiative decay mechanisms that a bounded, oscillating electron could experience. One that comes to mind is electron-phonon coupling. The oscillating electrons perturb the binding between nearby atoms, effectively "deforming" the lattice in a time-dependent manner (appropriately characterized by the so-called  deformation potential). This process can excite phonons and other coherent vibrations, which result in a dampening of the electron oscillation in a nonradiative way. I believe this type of coupling accounts for much of the mid-infrared absorption spectra of insulators, semiconductors, and molecules.